# Determining the number of values required to find the probabilities of a set of values

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Im trying to estimate when a random function with a set number of events will trend to its probability values and a ballpark on how much data I need to collect will help.

Is there an equation that says:
Given X number of possible events in a set; you can determine the probability of each event in that set using Y number of outcomes?
For example; if you had 2 possible events E1 and E2, you could need at least Y outcomes to statistically estimate the probability of both E1 and E2?

Is there any significance between probabilities in a set that would affect Y? For example, you would expect more outcomes are required to show that E1 has a probability of 2% than if it was 50%.

Comment: Seems that may be related to the Central Limit theorem, with $E_i$ as i.i.d. Random variables.

Answer (score 0):

The usual equation for sample size is 
  $$ n =  (z^*/m)^2 p(1-p)$$
where $m$ is the desired "margin of error" and $z^*$ is a factor close to 2. So, for small $p$ you need smaller $n$ to get the same *absolute* margin of error.